# No luck on installing .bin file (For Dell 32-bit Diagnostics)

Tags: package-management, dell, 32-bit, fan, diagnostic

I'm trying to install `Dell 32 Bit Diagnostics (Graphical User Interface version)`

To test  my fans..

Now..I download a file from Dell which is meant for Linux. the file format is:

```
GnuPG Signature for Linux Update Package
```

I understand it sounds dumb but I have no idea what it means. I downloaded the .bin file.

I have tried doing this:

```
chmod a+x /file
```

followed by

```
sudo ./file
```

With the file being of course the full path of the bin file..

```
(/home/username/downloads/CL1386A0.bin)
```

I would get in response to that `command not found` from the terminal.

How to I freaking install that Dell diagnostics? no help files regarding bin files on Dell website..thanks Dell! o_o

Anyone care to help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a link on the Dell website to the file you mentioned [here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/driverdetails?driverid=9K2G4). If you follow this link and scroll down to the *Categories* list, you will find a category called "Installation Instructions" with a green arrow next to it. Click the arrow to display the installation instructions for this file. The installation instructions include information about how to run a Diagnostic Media Creation script in Linux.

You should also take note that some of the installation instructions in this section apply only to computers that run Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to run fine: it is not installable, as you run it from the downloaded `.bin` file. (If you wanted to install it, you would have to manually copy it to a system folder.)

Use the [download link from the site](https://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/driverdetails?driverid=9K2G4) or run

```
wget "http://downloads.dell.com/diags/CL1386A0.bin"
```

Now cd to the download folder. You can find the md5 signature with

```
md5sum CL1386A0.bin
```

and compare it to that listed under the 'checksum' drop down menu at [the Dell site](https://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/driverdetails?driverid=9K2G4).

While at the folder with the `.bin` file, make the file executable with

```
chmod u+x CL1386A0.bin
```

The bin file is a program that allows you to make a diagnostic cd or usb, and if you run it without superuser privileges you won't be able to create your diagnostic disks, etc.

As this is a graphical application, gksudo is preferred, so cd to the folder with the downloaded file and run:

```
gksudo ./CL1386A0.bin
```

You get this screen:

[image]